# Systemverilog: Is it possible to treat a macro like an array that can be indexed?

Tags: macros, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, is it possible to index a macro for a long hierarchical reference? i.e.

```
`define CONDENSED top.DUT.mod.sub_module.register_map
```

then do something like:

```
`CONDENSED.reg1[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro is just simple text substitution. The text pre-processor doing the substitition knows nothing about SystemVerilog syntax other than what a token is (a string, a numeric literal, an identifier, a comment). You can use any macro as long as the resulting text is legal SystemVerilog text. (and mind the rules about splitting text that makes up a token).

Answer (score 1):

You can even include indices in your macro:

```
`define MY_SELECTION(index0, index1) c0_a[index0].c1_a[index1].a

class c1;
  int a;
endclass

class c0;
  c1 c1_a[10];

  function new();
    foreach(c1_a[idx]) begin
      c1_a[idx] = new();
    end
  endfunction
endclass

module top;
  initial begin
    automatic c0 c0_a[10];

    foreach(c0_a[idx]) begin
      c0_a[idx] = new();
    end

    `MY_SELECTION(5, 6) = 8;
    $display("my_value: %0d", `MY_SELECTION(5, 6));

    `MY_SELECTION(5, 6)[0] = 1;
    $display("my_value: %0d", `MY_SELECTION(5, 6));
  end
endmodule
```

The output of this code is this:

```
my_value: 8
my_value: 9
```

You can run this example on EDA Playground - https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4EZZ